# Cloudera manager is not starting

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to start cloudera cluster after restart of the machine but it is not staring the server:

Getting below error in cloudera-scm-server logs:

```
2014-12-23 21:29:26,870  WARN [Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@2e39060b:resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1841] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6ec135d6 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.6.109", user "scm", database "scm", SSL off
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
```

I tried to change the permission of db-data folder to 700 and also dropped the SCHEMA_VERSION table as per this [link](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Can-t-start-Cloudera-Manager-or-Hadoop-Services-after-hard/td-p/14380)  but no luck

**EDIT**

In DB logs from /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/db.log i got following FATAL error:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.6.109", user "scm", database "scm", SSL off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem

One of the other application that i am running updated the host file. So it was having two entries for localhost(**Broken Host file**). After fixing that problem was resolved.